# Permission of external disk under Mac OS

Tags: permission, external-disk

I plug an external disk to the laptop whose system is Mac OS, but I can't create files/folders, or rename files in the disk... The `Sharing & Permissions` is `You can only read`.

Does anyone know how to modify this permission?

Comment: What format is this drive in? NTFS, HFS, etc.?

Comment: NTFS... The disk can be written under Ubuntu/Windows automatically...

Comment: By default, NTFS disks are read only in OS X without additional software.

Comment: Short answer - OS X can't write to NTFS partitions without installing an additional package (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X can't write to NTFS natively - you'll need to install a package like [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/)/NTFS-3G or [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) to write to NTFS partitions.

From the BootCamp [Apple Support KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1656):

> During installation, the Microsoft Windows installer asks me to format
>   the Windows partition using NTFS or FAT. Which should I use?
>
> If the partition is 32 GB or smaller, you can use either FAT or NTFS.
>   If it's larger than 32 GB, or you are installing Microsoft Vista, then
>   you can only format it using NTFS. **Mac OS X can read and write FAT
>   volumes, but only read NTFS volumes.** Refer to the Microsoft Windows
>   documentation if you are not sure which best suits your needs.